# hide and show image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two image and two button in a div, Now process is when i click on button 1 then image 1 show same as in button 2.. now my problem is i want both image hide when i click in any part of body.. Now my problem is when i click on body it will hide but not able to show images on button click.

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHh3/1/)

HTML

```
<input type='button' id='btn1' value='button1'>
    <img src="abc.jpg" id='img1'>
        <input type='button' value='button2' id='btn2'>
    <img src="abc.jpg" id='img2' >
```

Js

```
$('#btn1').click()(function(){
       $('#img1').show();
                       $('#img2').hide();   
                  });
$('#btn2').click()(function(){
       $('#img2').show();
                       $('#img1').hide();   
                  });

$('body').click()(function(){
 $('#img1').hide();   
     $('#img1').hide();   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#btn1').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#img1').show();
    $('#img2').hide();
});
$('#btn2').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#img2').show();
    $('#img1').hide();
});
$('body').click(function () {
    $('#img1,#img2').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bJHh3/2/)**

You were using the click function incorrectly, plus your click events on the buttons were also bubbling up the DOM to the event you placed on the body.

Comment: What error do you get on your project? Do you have other code that could be interfering?

Comment: NOt get any error e.stoppropagation not work on it.. when i click on button1 image will be show and then hide due to body click function

Comment: i'm using 1.4.1 version on jquerry

Comment: Make sure you're using `e.stopPropagation` and not `e.stoppropagation`, the case matters. Nothing in my solution wouldn't work in JQ 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('body').click(function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if(!target.is('#btn1') || !target.is('#btn2')) {
           $('#img1').hide();   
         $('#img1').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: or you can use condition as if((target.id != 'btn1' || (target.id != '#btn2')) {